# How to test deep linking on Android?

Tags: adb, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I am trying to test Deep linking(locally) on Android. I was able to test on iOS with this link:

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted exp://127.0.0.1:19000/–/challenges/[SHARE-TOKEN]
```

For Android I tried:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d “exp://192.168.100.7:19000/–/challenges/[SHARE-TOKEN]” com.myapp.android
```

But I get this message: ***Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent.***

(ref: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html#test-deep-linking-on-ios)

Is there any way I can test deep linking on Android or am I missing something?

Comment: make sure to use regular double quote `"` symbols. not the typographic `“”`ones like in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this:

```
adb shell "am start 'exp://192.168.100.7:19000/–/challenges/[SHARE-TOKEN]'"
```

Comment: Have been struggling with this for a day now :) Thanks for your help.